# saving interactive plot as html

Tags: python, panel, holoviews, hvplot

I want to create an interactive dashboard as a standalone-application, being launched with only Firefox.
Here's some simple example code with two buttons and a plot.
it's exporting an html-file. but the elements seem not to react, when opened in Firefox...

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hvplot.pandas 
import panel as pn 
import holoviews as hv



np.random.seed(1234)
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']
adf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 4), columns=cols)
bdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 4), columns=cols)
adf['Type'] = 'A'
bdf['Type'] = 'B'

df = pd.concat([adf,bdf])
df.index.names = ['idx']

typebutton = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(name='Typebutton', options=['A','B'],button_type='success')
dfi = df.interactive(width=800)
df_inter = (dfi[dfi.Type == typebutton])

#df_inter
plot = df_inter.hvplot(kind='box', y=['Col1','Col2','Col3', 'Col4'], legend=False)
plot

template = pn.template.FastListTemplate(
    title='stackoverflow export panel to html', 
    sidebar=[pn.pane.Markdown("## Settings"),
             'Interactive Elements',typebutton], 
    main=[plot.panel()],
    accent_base_color="#88d8b0",
    header_background="#88d8b0",
)

template.servable();

from bokeh.resources import INLINE
template.save('interactive_elements.html', resources=INLINE)
```

Comment: what exactly is not working or not interactive?

Comment: Chart works for me, buttons are clickable but do not execute any function (as expected) - however the thing loaded quite a bit - you might have problems fetching the resources (firewall?) - try opening the html in a different browser and/or use a direct connection

Comment: There are two buttons which let you switch between which dataframe is ploted! In the HTML-File the buttons are click-able but the plot isn't changing